Unable to fetch activity runs from ADF
I am trying to fetch all the activities of a pipeline running in azure data factory and used this as guide: Activity Runs. I am trying to implement this in postman to check the details.
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}/queryActivityruns?api-version=2018-06-01

used this to run the query. All my values for subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, factoryName and runID are correct. I know this as I am able to fetch the details about the pipeline using this as my guide: pipeline details and this gives the expected output.
my request body is:

my output is:

I expected the values field to be populated with list of activities. And further my activities are in trigger mode only

Since you have given correct run_id, pipeline name, resource group name, subscription details in the API, one possibility to get the empty response is that there are no activity runs associated with the pipeline run.

Verify that there are activity runs associated with the pipeline run. You can do this by going to the ADF portal and checking the pipeline run details.

If there are no activity runs associated with the pipeline run, then the response will be empty.

Try using a different tool to make the API call. For example, you can try using PowerShell or Azure CLI to make the API call and see if you get a different response. You can check in the Microsoft document on Activity Runs - Query By Pipeline Run itself. Click the Try it button in the code snippet and give all the details and check.




Solved the problem by changing the request body:
{
    "filters": [],
    "orderBy": [
        {
            "orderBy": "ActivityRunStart",
            "order": "DESC"
        }
    ],
    "lastUpdatedAfter": "2824-07-01T07:36:18.68422787",
    "lastUpdatedBefore": "2024-07-01T09:21:58.3092"
}


I could not get the activities as the filter parameter and orderby parameter were not added

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
